# Only code completion / code sense which starts with @ is not working in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, code-completion

Suddenly, only code completion which starts with @ has stopped working in all Xcode projects in Xcode 6.

[image]

About a week ago, after upgrading to Xcode 6.0.1, I tried to use Debug View Hierarchy, then not only Xcode but also my entire Mac system crashed and it restarted. Since then, if I remember correctly, The problem has started to happen.

Most code completions are working correctly, like NSLog().

[image]

But, only code completion which starts with @, like @"string", @[array, ...], hasn't been working in all of my Xcode projects. When I type @, I can't see an automatic code completion popup window for NSString, id, NSArray, and so on. The code completion popup window automatically doesn't show up, but when I type the esc key, it shows up.

[image]

- I tried deleting Derived Data from Organizer in Xcode, but It didn't solve the issue.
- I updated Xcode to 6.1 just today, but it didn't work.
- I tried re-installing Xcode 6.1 with deleting all files at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode, and it didn't work either.

Even in a new Xcode project, there's the same issue. One of the weirdest points is that this code completion issue happens in my all Xcode projects regardless of when they are created. Also, the code completion for only @ doesn't work.

The code completion for @ is used very often. It's a sooo pain in the neck... It would be great if you could give me any advice to solve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried deleting Xcode and re-installing?

Comment: @Acey I tried re-installing Xcode 6.1 with deleting files at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode last night, and it didn't work.

Comment: I have the same issue. When I updated 6.0.1 to 6.1 , I could see  this issue was fixed. But a day later I have this issue again.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Apple has changed the behavior of this. So I guess get used to it.

I know it sucks, but at least you can change it to something else.

If someone knows how to get it back to like in Xcode 5 that would be awesome!

[image: Change this]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is good to know that not only me has this issue. Hope Apple will get it back as before in the future.

Comment: apple has been an as*ole for sometime now. Everytime they release something, they break a lot of previous functionality, not only in xcode but ios8, iphone 6 design, etc, etc. I have xcode6 installed and it was working as xcode5 until out of nothing, stop working with ESC for code completion and cancelling at the same time. So, it looks like it CAN work with the same comand, THAT's how it was working before xcode6, I just think apple has been going to the bathroom in the same place they eat.